# Not able to get valid response from Paypal after successful payment

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

This is my first post in Stackoverflow. Till now I got best solutions from this site without posting any question from this website.

This is regarding Paypal integration to my website. I am struggling from last 1 month. I tried in many ways but not succeed. Coming to my problem, I am not getting valid response from Paypal. Some times TXN Id is empty and some times it is working. Please check the below code and correct me.

This is the final Query String which goes to Paypal

```
   business=xxxxxxxxxxxx&item_name_1=Dell_laptop%29&amount_1=50&item_number_1=10&return=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxx.com%2Fpayments.php&cancel_return=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxxxxxx.com%2Fpayment-not-sucess.php¤cy_code=CAD¬ify_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxxxxx.com%2Fpayments.php&no_note=0&country=USA&cmd=_cart&upload=1
```

**Payments.php**

```
        if (!isset($_GET['tx']) && !isset($_GET['st'])){

        $header = array("Content-type: text/html", "multipart/form-data");

        $querystring = "business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";

        $querystring .= "item_name_1=".urlencode($exam_name_1)."&";
        $querystring .= "amount_1=".urlencode($amount_1)."&";
        $querystring .= "item_number_1=".urlencode($item_number_1)."&";

        if(($amount_2>0) && ($item_number_2 !='')){
        $querystring .= "item_name_2=".urlencode($exam_name_2)."&";
        $querystring .= "amount_2=".urlencode($amount_2)."&";
        $querystring .= "item_number_2=".urlencode($item_number_2)."&";
        }

        $querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
        $querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";

        //$querystring .= "rm=".urlencode($rm)."&";
        $querystring .= "currency_code=".urlencode($currency_code)."&";
        $querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url)."&";
        $querystring .= "no_note=".urlencode($no_note)."&";
        $querystring .= "country=".urlencode($country)."&";
        $querystring .= "cmd=".urlencode($cmd)."&";
        $querystring .= "upload=".urlencode($upload);
        header("Location: http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?".$querystring);

       }
        else{    // Response from Paypal................
        echo $payment_gross=$_REQUEST['amt']; 
        echo $txn_id=$_REQUEST['tx'];
        echo $payment_status=$_REQUEST['st'];

            header("Location: xxxx.php");

             }
```

**Paypal Settings :**

Auto return : ON

Return Url : http://www.xxxxxxx.com/payments.php

Notify Url : http://www.xxxxxxx.com/payments.php

PDT : on

IPN :  Enabled..

Answer (score 0):

For getting proper response from paypal after successful payment you have to mention success url in your array which you are sending to paypal

```
 if (!isset($_GET['tx']) && !isset($_GET['st'])){

    $header = array("Content-type: text/html", "multipart/form-data");

    $querystring = "business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";

    $querystring .= "item_name_1=".urlencode($exam_name_1)."&";
    $querystring .= "amount_1=".urlencode($amount_1)."&";
    $querystring .= "item_number_1=".urlencode($item_number_1)."&";

    if(($amount_2>0) && ($item_number_2 !='')){
    $querystring .= "item_name_2=".urlencode($exam_name_2)."&";
    $querystring .= "amount_2=".urlencode($amount_2)."&";
    $querystring .= "item_number_2=".urlencode($item_number_2)."&";
    }

    $querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";

    //$querystring .= "rm=".urlencode($rm)."&";
    $querystring .= "currency_code=".urlencode($currency_code)."&";
    $querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url)."&";
    //Added Line
    $querystring .= "success_url=".urlencode($notify_url)."&";
    $querystring .= "no_note=".urlencode($no_note)."&";
    $querystring .= "country=".urlencode($country)."&";
    $querystring .= "cmd=".urlencode($cmd)."&";
    $querystring .= "upload=".urlencode($upload);
    header("Location: http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?".$querystring);

   }
    else{    // Response from Paypal................
    echo $payment_gross=$_REQUEST['amt']; 
    echo $txn_id=$_REQUEST['tx'];
    echo $payment_status=$_REQUEST['st'];

        header("Location: xxxx.php");

         }
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Sorry for the late reply. can you please explain the diff between Return Url and Sucess url. i already mentioned that Return url.

Comment: Its a simple difference when the transaction is successful paypal looks for success url for redirecting back to your website with other values but if it is not found paypal will look for return url and get back to their without any value.